# Return TreeMap as value from Guava's cache

Tags: java, dictionary, caching, treemap, google-guava-cache

I have a map as defined below:

```
Map<Pair<String,String>>, TreeMap<Long, Long> targetMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to add eviction and maximum size properties to it, as we do for cache through Guava. Is there a way to handle this logic through Guava's cache? I want to avoid writing custom code for handling the additional properties for my map.